# How to join logged in user and user records within database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, authentication

I'm working with the ASP.NET Membership Provider with the SQL backend for the first time and I've encountered something that smells, which tells me I'm either doing it wrong or just haven't thought it all the way through...

The Membership provider crates a few tables including the default, `webpages_Membership` which tracks the user properties like username.  In my database for the application I have an `employees` table that tracks all of the user data for my employees.  The `employees` table has a unique identifier `id` which is used as a foreign key column to multiple other tables to track things like who updated the records, created them, who they're assigned to, who left comments, etc.

The first assumption I've made is that I don't want to put business logic and fields within the `webpages_Membership` table nor do I use the `UserId` column in foreign key relationships.

The second assumption that I've made is that I'm controlling the registration process entirely and I can simply join the `webpages_Membership` table and my `employees` table together based off of the email address field since the user's login will be forced to be their email.

#### this just smells horrible in my mind right now...

Taking this value `User.Identity.Name` and querying the `employees` table in my database just to get an `Employee` object populated so I can set an `Id` field on a record seems wrong.

- What should I be doing for this?
- What is the best way to join the membership data and the business objects data together?
- Should I even do that?
- Should I store the Employee object in the user's session to not go back to the database for every transaction?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a foreign key to `webpages_Membership.UserId` in your `employees` table?

Comment: There are a bunch of other fields that I use on the employees table for tracking things like who their manager is, what their role in the org is.  

My assumption is that I don't want to modify these membership tables, but I could clearly be mistaken.

Comment: The joys of going from Intranet apps with Active Directory to Internet apps :)

Comment: And yet there's no reason to not use AD anymore.  If for a corporation, spin up a new Internet AD server and manage your memberships there just like before, or if a hosted solution consider hosted AD, like what Azure offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Because if you are using some of the latest version, you can use the SimpleMembershipProvider which allows you to use a different model and database structure.

[Check this blog post from Jon Galloway for more details.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20jongalloway%20%28Jon%20Galloway%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Comment: MVC4 on .NET 4.5  

I like the look of the SimpleMemershipProvider...  Will research it a bit.